# How to highlight the exact word I am searching for in my string rather than just beginning of string?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a `SearchDelegate` to search for a word within my list of strings. It works perfectly in searching for the word within string, but the problem is that it highlights from the start of string rather than just the word itself.

The behaviour can be seen from the screenshot below, I am searching for "alice", it manages to find strings in which the word exists but how do I highlight the word as I type??

[image]

Below is my full code for the `SearchDelegate` function, if that helps.

```
class TextSearch extends SearchDelegate<String>{
  //List to show when query box is empty
  List<String> emptyList = [''];
  List<String> searchList;
  //constructor for passing the list in
  TextSearch(this.searchList);

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: (){
          query = '';
        },
      )
    ];
    //throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        progress: transitionAnimation,
      ),
      onPressed: (){
        //below is similar to Navigator.pop: close this, go to previous page
        this.close(context, null);
      },
    );
    //throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Text(query),
    );
    //throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? emptyList
        : searchList.where((string) => string.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())).toList();

    return _WordSuggestionList(
      query: this.query,
      suggestions: suggestionList,
      onSelected: (String suggestion){
        this.query = suggestion;
        showResults(context);
      },
    );
  }
}

// Suggestions list widget displayed in the search page.
class _WordSuggestionList extends StatelessWidget {
  const _WordSuggestionList({this.suggestions, this.query, this.onSelected});

  final List<String> suggestions;
  final String query;
  final ValueChanged<String> onSelected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestions.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        final String suggestion = suggestions[i];
        return ListTile(
          //leading: query.isEmpty ? Icon(Icons.history) : Icon(null),
          // Highlight the substring that matched the query.
          title: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              text: suggestion.substring(0, query.length),
              style: textTheme.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                  text: suggestion.substring(query.length),
                  style: textTheme,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            onSelected(suggestion);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring` and `indexOf` to find the word in your search, like so:

```
String sentence = "Alice in Wonderland";
String query = "Alice";
String findAlice= sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(query), query.length);
```

Using RichText and TextSpan:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final regex = RegExp('(?= )');
  final sentence = "Alice in Wonderland";
  final query = "Alice";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordsList = sentence.split(regex);
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          for (final word in wordsList)
            TextSpan(
              text: word,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: word.contains(query)
                      ? Colors.purpleAccent
                      : Colors.white),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried what you suggested and changed the substring line in my above code to: ``text: suggestion.substring(suggestion.indexOf(query), query.length)``. 
 But got this error when I start typing in search: ``The following RangeError was thrown building:
Value not in range: -1``

Comment: @StuckInPhD Added an example using RichText and TextSpan. Hopefully, it makes sense now.